# How To add slash between seo friendly url in opencart

Tags: url, seo, opencart

When i add seo friendly url on opencart like 'abcd-test' or 'abcd-test.htm' it worked.
but when i added 'abcd-test/22123.htm', IT redirected to  'www.example.com/abcd-test/22123.htm' but it displayed

```
The page you requested cannot be found!
```

I already have a website in another framework other than opencart which is doing well on google ranking. but i need to move this website on opencart and i need to make same url for most of the pages. during that process my existing website have url like "www.example.com/category-s/12234.htm

so will any one facing same problem and any one have the solution for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found the answer:
>
> In opencart To dayplay
>   `www.example.com/test-abc/12234.htm`
>
> Here we need to have category or manufacturer with seo keyword `test-abc` and
>   `12234.htm` in product seo url.

```
Url/product
Url/parent-cat/product
Url/parent/child/product
```

so if I am in `www.example.com/test-abc`,
it is category page and if I am in `www.example.com/test-abc/12234.htm`, it means It is product page which beloigs to `test-abc` category.

> it work me

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to due to the way that OpenCart's router works. It takes the URL and delimits it on the forward slash. It then matches the key that is between the slashes to a variable value and ultimately routes based on that variable value.

For example:

`http://mysight.com/one/two/three` would be equivalent to something like `http://mysight.com/index.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3`.

Note: This example is not based on an OpenCart page it is merely explaining how OpenCart's router translates to raw PHP.

By including forward slashes in your SEO URL aliases OpenCart thinks that it needs to match keys that just don't exist and because it can't route to a valid page it simply redirects you to a default 404 page.

Comment: In opencart, when i have added single 'test.htm' like www.mywebsite.com/test.htm instead of www.mywebsit.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=41 then it works.  Do you have any solution for above problem about adding test/12322.htm

Comment: @SamirKarmacharya If you want a static a html page with that URL format you will have to create the test directory and the 12322.htm static file. Otherwise if Apache does not see a static file it will default to OpenCart's SEO router